# Setting default address in Jboss 8 Wildfly

Tags: jboss, wildfly-8

It's my first time deploying apps into web, I've successfully configured ubuntu 14.04 on server, installed java, placed Jboss 8.1.0.Final there.
I'v made also wildfly service. But the problem is that I don't know how to set jboss to start on my default address. For example I have vps555111.ovh.net adress how can I make it to start on that address?

/edit I figured it out how to set it to start it on my address but there's another problem - I was fallowing this tutorial http://www.itbuzzpress.com/wildfly-8-administration/getting-started-with-wildfly-8.html
and when I'm starting it as service it starts on 127.0.0.1:8080 address, anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit you standalone.xml file find the public interface:

```
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
```

And replace 127.0.0.1 with the IP Address you need or 0.0.0.0